# How to fix the broken MGRS Tools plugin?

Tags: qgis, plugins

Here the case: I have a plugin installed in .qgis2/python/plugins that remains broken and I can't make it work. I've found it here https://github.com/volaya/mgrs-tools. If any of you know the way to fix it I'll be so glad.

Hint: from forum I've heard it can come from dash characters in the plugin's folder name.

I use Windows 7 64-bits and QGIS 2.6

UPDATE:

It appears that running QGIS 2.10 32-bits solves my problem.
Meanwhile as the issue persists with 64-bit versions of QGIS I've just partly found an answer.

Comment: note to others: bug reported here https://github.com/volaya/mgrs-tools/issues/1

Comment: Did you have success with an earlier version of the tool?

Comment: I did write one of the two reports but no answer came from it. Stackexchange seems much more active.

Comment: @andrej: no i didn't good remarks i'll try to find where they are

Comment: You can browse through https://github.com/volaya/mgrs-tools/commits/master to get earlier versions, but even the first one is broken for me. It will not work with Windows 7 without re-compiling the lib to 64bit anyway.

Comment: Yes same for me here, just waiting for its creator to get an anwser now.

Answer (score 1):

The MGRS plugin has now been moved to the boundless repository. The repository can be added to the available python plugins as described [here](http://qgis.boundlessgeo.com/).

The MGRS plugin is documented on the [plugin page](http://boundlessgeo.github.io/qgis-plugins-documentation/mgrs/usage.html), and it seems to work with the current QGIS 2.14.

Disclaimer: I am not involved in boundless, but the original plugin author, Victor Volaya, is part of it. He has removed the plugin from his own github site linked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the plugin folder, removing the dash:

`move mgrs-tools mgrstools`

..or clone the git repository using a directory name without the dash.

`git clone https://github.com/volaya/mgrs-tools.git mgrstools`

or, now that the development has moved:

`git clone https://github.com/boundlessgeo/mgrs-tools.git mgrstools`